# Facebook: Unable to upload local image/ video to Facebook page form server side using graph API

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to upload a video to Facebook page from local storage using Form-data and graph API. You can have look at the code that I used below.
I have used multer to store the video file locally, that is received from the client side through API.  This is the code.

```js
var multer  =   require('multer');   
var storage =   multer.diskStorage({  
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {  
    callback(null, './utility/fb_files');  
  },  
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {  
    callback(null, file.originalname);  
  }  
});  
var upload_to_fb = multer({ storage : storage});  
module.exports = upload_to_fb;
```

The file gets saved in local storage successfully. But when I try to upload the same file to Facebook page through graph API , I get an error. Here is the API code.

```js
app.post('/api/document/post_to_fb_from_local', FB_upload.array('doc', 1), function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("req.files ", req.files)
    // console.log("req.files ", req)
    let company_id = getCompanyId(req);
    //console.log('company_id ' + company_id);
    var activeuser = retrieveDetails(req);
    if (
        !(
            req.files &&
            req.query.task_id &&
            req.query.action &&
            req.query.fileType &&
            req.query.accessToken &&
            req.query.page_id &&
            req.query.text
        )
    ) {
        return res.send(
            {
                status: false,
                message: "can't upload fields missing"
            });
    }
    let action = req.query.action;
    //console.log("activeuser ", activeuser);
    if (action == "video_image_post") {
        if (req.query.fileType == "video") {
            // var videoFile = new Blob(req.files.doc[0], { type: 'video/mp4' })
            let vid = './utility/fb_files/' + req.files[0].filename;
            let videoData = require('fs').createReadStream(vid);
            console.log('./../../utility/fb_files/' + req.files[0].filename);
            var url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + req.query.page_id + '/videos?access_token=' + req.query.accessToken +
                '&source=' + videoData +
                '&title=' + req.query.title +
                '&description=' + req.query.text;
        }
        request({
            url: url,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
            },
            method: 'POST'
        }, function (error, resp) {
            if (error || resp.statusCode != 200) {
                console.log("Failed to post");
                console.log(error);
                console.log(resp.body);
                body = resp.body;
                if (body.error) {
                    var error = body.error.message;
                    console.log("body  ", body)
                    console.error("Error returned from facebook: " + body.error.message);
                    if (body.error.code == 341) {
                        error = "You have reached the post limit for facebook. Please wait for 24 hours before posting again to facebook."
                        console.error(error);
                    }
                    res.send(error);
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                console.log("posted successfully")
                console.log("resp.body.id ", resp.body.id);
                console.log("resp.body ", resp.body);
                res.send({
                    "status": true,
                    "message": "posted successfully",
                    "body": resp.body
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And the error I get when I try to upload a video to the Facebook page is shown below.

```js
req.files  [ { fieldname: 'doc',
2|document.service     |     originalname: 'VID-20171112-WA0001.mp4',
2|document.service     |     encoding: '7bit',
2|document.service     |     mimetype: 'video/mp4',
2|document.service     |     destination: './utility/fb_files',
2|document.service     |     filename: 'VID-20171112-WA0001.mp4',
2|document.service     |     path: 'utility\\fb_files\\VID-20171112-WA0001.mp4',
2|document.service     |     size: 99540 } ]
2|document.service     | ./../../utility/fb_files/VID-20171112-WA0001.mp4
2|document.service     | Failed to post
2|document.service     | null
2|document.service     | {"error":{"message":"There was a problem uploading your video file. Please try again.","type":"OAuthException","code":390,"error_subcode":1363030,"is_transient":true,"error_user_title":"Video Upload Timeout","error_user_msg":"Your video upload timed out before it could be completed. This is probably because of a slow network connection or because the video you're trying to upload is too large. Please try again.","fbtrace_id":"Aia2DbzWdjepS1yMJIzX1CE"}}
```

Please help me in resolving the issue here.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why `Content-Type: application/json`? You stuffed all the data into the URL, and I don’t see any JSON encoding going on anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... Content-Type: application/json, worked when I tried to upload a video or image using a URL link. So , I thought to just it like that. Let me try to change that and see if it works

Comment: I have changed the mime type in the facebook graph api url according to the file mime type . but it it shows me the same error.

Comment: You are appending all the parameters to the URL, but you are using `method: 'POST'` – is the request library you are using there supposed to magically convert the URL parameters into a proper POST request body?

Comment: please have a look at this Facebook video publishing guide.  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/video-api/guides/publishing  . In this guide, they too have used POST method for uploading  a video. So, I did the same.

Comment: Of course the method to use is POST, I was questioning whether your way of appending all the data into the URL query string is actually the right way to do it. (Those would be GET parameters per se, so unless the request library you are using automatically “translates” those into a proper request body, I don’t see why this should work.)

Comment: I have used the same POST method to upload a video using a URL link and it worked fine .Only change in this case is I have used url link there ,and I have used local file data here. everything else is same. Anyway I will try using GET method once

Comment: The length of a URL is technically limited, so passing the URL to a video might work fine (that is not much data), but trying to append the whole binary content of a video file, is a different story, and likely to fail.

Comment: I have tried using GET method instead of POST. It returned details of the recent posts made on Facebook page. video did not get posted on Facebook page. I am out of options now.

Comment: I never said you should try GET, that makes no sense to begin with. What I am saying, is that your attempt is a crude mixture of GET _parameters_, with the request method POST - instead of a _proper_ POST request, that contains the data in the request body.